# Rails 4, Simple form: custom url not finding user by id properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have a bsic question regarfing a simple_form I have

Here is the form

```
  <%= simple_form_for(current_user, :url =>  nation_user_path(current_user), :method => :post) do |f| %>
        <%= f.input :selected_country, collection: @user_country_array, label: "Select a country to view data on (only countries represented are listed)", class: 'form-control' %>
        <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary" %></h3>
  <% end %>
```

routes.rb

```
resources :users do
   member do
     get :network
     post :nation
   end
end
```

user_controller

```
before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :nation]


 def nation
    @country = User.find(params[:user][:selected_country])
    @user_country_array = Array.new
    @user_country_array = User.all.map {|user| user.country }.reject{ |country| country.nil? }.uniq.sort
    @user_count = User.all.select { |u| u.user_complete == true }.count
    @user_json = User.all.group_by(&:iso).map{|k,v| [k, v.count, k.to_s.downcase]}.map {|c, v | ["code" => c, "value" => v, "flag" => c.to_s.downcase]}.flatten.to_json
    @sectiona =  User.all.group('practice').count.map { |k,v| [ "name" => k, "y" => v] unless k.nil?}.reject { |a| a.blank? }.flatten.to_json
    render 'country'
 end


def set_user
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end


# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:experience,
                               :kind,
                               :selected_country,
                             ])
end
```

And user.rb

```
  attr_accessor :selected_country
```

When I submit the form with a country I get...

```
  Couldn't find User with 'id'=American Samoa
```

I am struggling to see why the before action isn't setting the suer correctly and defaulting (it seems) to the value in the select box

Any suggestions on this....

Comment: Do you read the documentation for the [`find`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/find) method ? Maybe you should use [`find_by`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/find_by) in `@country = User.find_by(country: params[:user][:selected_country])`

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is that you're trying to `find` the `User` using the `selected_country` attribute:

```
@country = User.find(params[:user][:selected_country])
```

Because you're setting this as a pure string, it will attempt to look up your `User` with the country you selected.

If you want to look up a value with a string, you'd be best using the [`find_by`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by) method:

```
@country = User.find_by country: params[:user][:selected_country]
```

--

To be honest, your whole `nation` method is really bad (multiple heavy db calls etc). I would do the following:

```
 def nation
    @country = User.find_by country_params[:selected_country]
    @user_country_array = User.select(:country).distinct
    @user_count = User.where(user_complete: true).count
    @user_json = User.all.group_by(&:iso).map{|k,v| [k, v.count, k.to_s.downcase]}.map {|c, v | ["code" => c, "value" => v, "flag" => c.to_s.downcase]}.flatten.to_json #-> this needs to improve
    @sectiona =  User.all.group('practice').count.map { |k,v| [ "name" => k, "y" => v] unless k.nil?}.reject { |a| a.blank? }.flatten.to_json #-> this also needs to improve
    render :country
 end

 private

 def country_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:selected_country)
 end
```